# Let $ (x_{1}, x_{2}) \sim (y_{1}, y_{2})$ iff $x_{2} =y_{2}$ on $ \mathbb{R} ^{2}$ . Then $\mathbb{R} ^2 /\sim$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

Let $ (x_{1}, x_{2}) \sim (y_{1}, y_{2})$ iff $x_{2} =y_{2}$  on $ \mathbb{R} ^{2}$ . Then $\mathbb{R} ^2/\sim $ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$

I am using Willard's book and there the "identification space " $X / \sim$ is defined to be the decomposition space $ D$ whose elements are the equivalence classes for  $ \sim$.

I think that by following the definition the topology on the decomposition space is the trivial one( if we consider $\mathbb{ R} ^2 $ to have the standard topology). But, if this is true I don't see how the spaces are homeomorphic. Thanks for any hints / suggestions!

Comment: What _are_ the equivalence classes of $\sim$? Can you describe what they look like?

Comment: I think they look just like horizontal lines, and so since lines are closed in the plane( i think). This would mean we need all lines to be open in the standard topology

Comment: No, it means that the _points_ of $\Bbb R^2/\sim$ are the _lines_ of the plane (the equivalence classes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\pi : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$
\pi(x,y) = y
$$
is a continuous surjection. Furthermore, $(x_1,x_2)\sim (y_1,y_2)$ iff $\pi((x_1,x_2)) = \pi((y_1,y_2))$. Thus you have an induced map :
$$
\overline{\pi} : \mathbb{R}^2/\sim \to \mathbb{R}
$$
given by
$$
\overline{\pi}([(x,y)]) = \pi(x,y) = y
$$
This is well-defined (by what I said above), surjective, and also injective (why?).

Furthermore, it is continuous (this you need to explain to yourself). Once you do that, it is the required homeomorphism.